# I could not understand this sentence entirely

Tags: words, syntax

I know the translation of the sentence, but I don't understand some structures. Is もし from a verb? And what does いくら mean here?

> 車を運転する時は**いくら注意してもしすぎる**ことはない。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are parsing it wrong.

> 車を運転する時はいくら注意してもしすぎることはない。

In parts,

`車を運転する時は` means "when you drive a car" and explains in what circumstances the latter part of the sentence applies.

いくら注意してもしすぎることはない

いくら = how much to / to what degree

注意 has two meanings. Either to warn someone or to be mindful of something.

して = て-form of する

も - this makes it a pattern いくら**Vて**も - "no matter how much". In this case, roughly "how careful you are"

しすぎる = し is the stem of する and すぎる is to do something too much. 
~ことはない = there is no such thing as ~.

So for the whole:

When driving a car, there is no such thing as being too careful.

or

When you're driving a car, you can never be too careful.

Comment: I think you can understand it by saying a second 注意 has been left out: いくら注意しても**注意**しすぎることはない (perhaps [left-node raising](http://phiz.c.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~yatabe/left.pdf)).  I have the feeling, though, that this is an attempt to approximate the English expression "can't be too careful" rather than a natural way to express a similar idea in Japanese.